# ASP.NET Issues with global.asax on GoDaddy.com

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

I am using Visual Studio 2012 to upload my website and having trouble getting it to show in my domain. Everything uploads on GoDaddy ftp. I talked with GoDaddy and they said that my global.asax file was causing the issue. But they couldn't tell me exactly what is was because they are not experts in code. He verified that the global.asax was the issue and not the web.config file. I have provided my global.asax file below. Any help would be awesome so I could get this website published and working on my domain. Thanks!

```
Imports System.Web.Optimization

Public Class Global_asax
Inherits HttpApplication

Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires when the application is started
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)
    AuthConfig.RegisterOpenAuth()
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
End Sub

Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires at the beginning of each request
End Sub

Sub Application_AuthenticateRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires upon attempting to authenticate the use
End Sub

Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires when an error occurs
End Sub

Sub Application_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires when the application ends
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What is exactly the error you are getting?

Comment: Page not found. Its like its not even reading my code. But GoDaddy confirmed that it was my global.asax file. And confirmed that the server end was running properly. If I use my phone to look up the site then I get page not found. 502 Bad Gateway-Response Error. Not sure if this helps but that's all im getting. Its like it doesn't exist. I run projects from VS 2010 and I can upload fine but 2012 seems like its causing issues.

Comment: This is a Web Forms application, right? Assuming you have a default.aspx page, if you type http://domain.com/default.aspx you get the error? The error is an IIS error or a "Server error in application"?

Comment: Yes this is a web forms application. I am not getting any error page. Usually when I do something that causes an error I see that Red Error page saying Server error in application but this is not what im getting. WHen I type in domain.com/default.aspx I am not getting anything. Here is the actual site im trying to hit and that's what im getting: www.jenniferandjordan122813.com

Comment: If you delete the Global.asax file, what will happen? What error are you getting? If you try to see a static file, an image or a plain html file, what happens?

Comment: I deleted the global.asax file from my project. Published the site to GoDaddy again and it is working now. Why would this work? Thanks for helping me just trying to understand why global.asax file is there to start with? Does GoDaddy already provide a global.asax and it was conflicting?

Comment: I am not sure why this was happening. Global.asax is an application file, there is not a 'common' Global.asax file on each server.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an empty Global.asax file, e.g. commenting all the code lines from it, as it is in the code snippet below.

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires when the application is started
    ' BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)
    ' AuthConfig.RegisterOpenAuth()
    ' RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
End Sub
```

A next step is to uncomment one at a time and then detect the one that is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"> 
</modules>
</system.webServer>
```